# Ending a game when two nodes collide

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skscene

I have two separate nodes with their own physics bodies, and when they collide, an SKScene with the high score and replay button should present itself. This is how my scene is called:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
  gameOver()

    print("gameOver")
}
```

And this is how my physics bodies for my nodes are set up:

```
   func createDown(position: CGPoint) -> SKNode {
    let circleNode = SKSpriteNode()
    let circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "first@2x")
    circleNode.position = CGPointMake(position.x, position.y)
    circleNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 30)
    circleNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    circle.size = CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)
    circleNode.addChild(circle)
    circleNode.name = "circleNode"
    circle.name = "CIRCLE"
    let up = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -9000, duration: 100)
     physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = blackCategory
    circleNode.runAction(up)
    return circleNode
}
func playerPhysics() {
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 30)
    player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
  player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
     player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = blackCategory
}
```

And here is my gameOver function:

```
 func gameOver() {
   gameEnd = true
     let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
     let scene = GameOver(size: self.scene!.size)
     view!.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)


}
```

Am I missing something? Will post more code if necessary.

Comment: Is method createDown defined in the scene or in some other class ? Can you show how you've defined your categories ? If createDown method is defined in scene, then you forgot to set categoryBitMask and contactTestBitMask for circle node...

Answer (score 0):

Just use intersectsNode and call gameOver() when the two nodes collide.

`if yourNode.intersectsNode(yourSecondNode) { 
gameOver() 
}`

SKNode Class Reference: [SKNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/)

Comment: Also, how would I declare my createDown(position: CGPoint) func globally?

Comment: Make a struct holding the function inside of it (outside of a class) , and make an instance of that struct anywhere that you need it

Comment: I got an error "cannot convert to type SKNode" when I tried this.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the physics world as a contact delegate for your methods to work.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

And like Whirlwind said, you need to set your `categoryBitMask` and `contactTestBitMask` for the circle node.

Then everything should work. I hope I could help.